# Bug fixes for Pokémon Gold & Silver 3ds Virtual Console?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

Just wondering if any of the numerous bugs in the original Gold and Silver are present in the recently released Virtual Console verions. I'm aware that glitches such as the shiny Ditto glitch are still possible to execute, but I'm more interested in the ''game breaking'' bugs. For example the catch rate bug (status conditions don't affect catch rate) or how Poké balls such as the Moon ball doesn't actually have an added effect (supposed to increase catch rate for Pokémon who evolve via a moon stone).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of the bugs present in the original games were fixed. The Virtual Console re-releases are identical to the originals in every way.

Comment: Technically they must have been changed a little, to support wireless battling and trading, and moving Pokémon to Pokémon Bank. Having said that, that has no bearing on the glitches.

Comment: @J.G. The wrapping emulator is what enables wireless communication, not a change to the ROM. Bank support is through direct modification of the ROM’s save data, but not the ROM itself. Sorry if I’m being pedantic.

Comment: @zero298 That's much clearer: the ROM is unchanged.